# Drupal: imageField Crop: Suggest initial cropping?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Can I initialize the cropping area (In order to suggest a default one), with the Imagecrop module ?

I want my users to crop images in the same way...

thanks

Update: code lines in `imagefield_crom.js`

```
setSelect: [
          parseInt($(".edit-image-crop-x", widget).val()),
          parseInt($(".edit-image-crop-y", widget).val()),
          parseInt($(".edit-image-crop-width", widget).val()) + parseInt($(".edit-image-crop-x", widget).val()),
          300 + parseInt($(".edit-image-crop-y", widget).val())
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagefield Crop uses the following jQuery plugin http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html

The function that you should be interested in is `setSelect` which sets the initial cropping area.

You can have a look in the file `imagefield_crop.js` (in the imagefield_crop module folder) where the function `setSelect` is being called. The default there is to set the selection area to the whole image -- you might want to recommend some other size and starting coordinates.

**Alternative Answer** 
Check out http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop

Comment: do you mean the lines I've added to the question ? I've changed one of them (hardcoded 300) but it didn't work

Comment: Sorry I didn't try it myself though I really think that this is the place where the magic happens. Did you get an opportunity to go through this in firebug javascript debugger? Did you check out imagecrop? I haven't deeply explored that but it could be what you want.

Comment: In answer to your question, the lines you have posted seem to the correct ones that will control the initial select area, I believe. BTW http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop is a different from imagefield_crop

Comment: yeah it works. The only thing is that I need to move or resize the dragged area to save the changes. In other words, the preview is not considered for the real cropping. Do you know how can I crop using the default cropping without having to drag the area at all ?

Comment: What works imagecrop or fiddling with `setSelect` ? -- not clear from your comment.

Comment: The initial cropping changes, and I can set it as I want. However it is not cropping the image. In other words, I have to make a change to the cropping area with the mouse (dragging or resizing) in order to make it crop the image.

Comment: You should explore issuing the `onSelect` event. This event is fired when the selection ends. See the Jcrop manual. Another scenario is to not change `imagfield_crop.js` but explicitly issue a `setSelect` command later on in some js included from a custom module. You'll have to do some jQuery hacking basically :-)

Comment: uhm.. yeah.. the point is that I don't want to change the cropping area when an old node is edited.. you know what I mean, I want to preserve the cropping area. I only want to change it if it is a new image.

Comment: Yes, I understand. This requires some thought. I'll play around with it if I get some time.